# Trying to write to file within nested loop, but only getting one record

Tags: python, loops, nested

Thank you ahead of time for any help you can be in solving this mystery here. I'm a newbie to Python, so you may have much more sophisticated ways of making this work. Please bear with my code.

I'm trying to figure out why when I print the each_file and awl_counter variables I get the list of items that I want, but when I go to write them to the file, I only have one record. I want to make this all work within the loops because there's a lot of recursive activity happening.

Here's my code:

```
    ## Mini-project 3 (Task A): Calculate percentage of words in ICNALE_Smoke corpus 
##                         texts that occurs in the AWL
## Assignment:
##   1. Read in a list of AWL words
##   2. Iterate through all learner files
##   3. Clean each learner file
##  4. Calculate number of AWL words / total number of words
##  5. Output your results


# Import Packages
from __future__ import division     # Allows for division functions
import string                       # Allows string functions
import glob                         # Makes a list of all files in a folder
# import nltk                         # Imports natural language toolkit (NLTK)
from collections import Counter     # Allows us to create dictionaries for frequency counts
import fileinput                    # Allows us to concatenate contents of separate text files


##
## 1. Read in a list of AWL words
##
awl_word_list = file ("AWL.txt", "rU").read().split("\n")   # Copy contents of AWL to variable and split


##
## 2. Iterate through all learner files
##
smoke_file_list = glob.glob("ICNALE_500_smoke/*.txt")  # Collect list of ICNALE texts 


# Central loop to perform steps 2-5
for each_file in smoke_file_list:

    current_file_container = []     # Opens empty list for file contents

    # Append contents of current file to current_file_container variable
    with open(each_file) as current_file:
        current_file_container.append(current_file.read())

    # Convert current_file_container (list) to string       
    clean_string = str(current_file_container)

    # Convert clean_string to lowercase
    clean_string_lower = clean_string.lower()

    # Remove punctuation marks from clean_string_lower
    punctuation_marks = [",",".","?","'",'"',"!",":",";","(",")","''","``","--"]
    for these_particular in punctuation_marks:
        clean_string_lower = clean_string_lower.replace(these_particular, "")

    # Remove additional characters from clean_string_lower
    clean_string_final = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, clean_string_lower)

    # Split clean_string_final and establish total word count
    clean_string_final_split = clean_string_final.split(" ")
    total_word_count = len(clean_string_final_split)

    # Establish and reset counter for each Smoke text file
    awl_counter = 0

    for current_word in clean_string_final_split:
        if current_word in awl_word_list:
            awl_counter += 1
        else:
            continue


#   Open text file and output tab-delimited filename with percentage of AWL hits 
#   with open("Percent of Words in AWL.txt", "w") as write_to_file:
#       write_to_file.write(each_file + "\t" + str(awl_counter / total_word_count))
```

Comment: So, your "Percent of Words in AWL.txt" only contained one line record of your last smoke file, but you want it contains ALL record of all smoke files, each line corresponds to one smoke file?

Comment: If so, try modify `open("Percent of Words in AWL.txt", "w")` to `open("Percent of Words in AWL.txt", "a")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use append `"a"` option to add more text to a file. If you use `"w"` it will rewrite the content.

```
with open("Percent of Words in AWL.txt", "a") as write_to_file:  # ---> 'a' == append content
#       write_to_file.write(each_file + "\t" + str(awl_counter / total_word_count))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification! I wound up putting the contents in a list and writing them outside of the loop. But I had no idea there was the append option in the open command. I really appreciate that.